# Как обновить значки рабочего стола| CMD or Powershell | Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

**Как обновить значки рабочего стола** при помощи `CMD` или `Powershell`.

*Возможно поможет это*

**┏ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶ ╶  ┓**

Обновить значки рабочего стола можно и без

помощи данных программ при помощи `F5` или `ПКМ>Обновить`.

Comment: Ну по нажатию кнопки [F5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59668242/) решение есть. Но как по мне, выглядит оно сомнительно. Можно и с помощью уведомления [SHChangeNotify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986869/).

Comment: @Daemon-5 данный способ не помог